# Force bootstrap datepicker rerendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date, datepicker

I'm using the [bootstrap datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/).  I have two datepickers: one for the start date and one for the end date.  The end date should always be either on or after the start date, so for user friendliness I would like to disable dates in the end date datepicker that are earlier than the start dates.

Based on the documentation, I'm doing something like:

```
$endDate.datepicker({
  onRender: function(date) {
    return date.valueOf() < startDate.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';        
  },                                                                      
});
```

This works, but the problem is that `onRender` is not called every time the datepicker opens or the start date changes (which is what I need).  Is there any way to either force the datepicker to re-render, which I can do when the start date changes, or an event that fires each time the end date datepicker opens where I can control whether certain dates are disabled?

Comment: did you try to use the "changeDate" event?

Comment: @Seb33300 is there a way to trigger rendering from `changeDate`?

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same problem today. I fixed it by changing the enddate value on the change event of my start date.

```
.on('changeDate', function(ev) {
       var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
       newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() +1);
       endDate.setValue(newDate);
```

This forces the end date to re-render when changing the startDate.

Comment: What about if the end date has already been selected (and is valid)?

Comment: You could add a conditional. 

`if (endDate.valueOf() < startDate.valueOf()){ //code }`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `fill()` method:

```
startdate = $(startdate).datepicker().on('changeDate', function () {
    enddate.fill(); // it's will trigger enddate onRender function
});
enddate = $(startdate).datepicker({
    onRender: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() < startDate.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';        
    }
});
```

Hope it can help.

Comment: I got this error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fill is not a function`. How did you manage to get it to work? There is no reference to `fill()` method in the documentation https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#. Any idea?